# How can I throw an error when starting an expressjs server?

Tags: javascript, express

Here's my minimal code example:

```
...

const url = typeof process.env.url === 'string' ? process.env.url : {do not start a server}
...
server.start(options, ({ port }) => console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

How can I throw an error (or just print out something) and avoid starting a server if `process.env.url` is not set (please see the code sample).

Comment: Put somthing which checks it early on then use process.exit(). `if (!process.env.url) console.log('error..'); process.exit(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple if condition would suffice:

```
const url = process.env.url || false
if(!url) {
   console.log('error..'); 
   process.exit(0)
}

...
```

Comment: I believe it won't pass Flow's check (i.e., url may be a string or a boolean). Is there a way to modify it? I was thinking about setting it to an empty string otherwise but it isn't probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Why would it be true or false, that's not a url. What are you trying to achieve? If its for somthing like binding it to a domain or for some other module like acme-client then you would be better off actually parsing the url core package https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_host just to be sure, and if its not a url do whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply throw the error and exit the process:

```
function notValid() {
  throw new Error('The passed url is not valid!');
  process.exit()
}

const url = typeof process.env.url === 'string' ? process.env.url : notValid();

server.start(options, ({ port }) => console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Comment: Because his condition is based on the type, it doesn't check if exist or not.
Anyway, i agree that would be preferable and better something like:
const url = process.env.url || 'http://localhost/'

Comment: We talking environment vars here, why would it be anything other than a string or undefined?

Comment: I agree with you, what i mean is that i was just replying to his specific question, not telling him what to do with his code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = typeof process.env.url === 'string' ? process.env.url : new Error("Error Message")
if(url instanceof Error) {
  throw url;
}
server.start(options, ({ port }) => console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`));
```

You can change `Error Message` to any message you want and that will break the server (with error thrown)

#### Without Error

```
const url = typeof process.env.url === 'string' ? process.env.url : null
if(!url) {
   process.exit(0);
}
server.start(options, ({ port }) => console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`));
```